# Filtering an assets file - android

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to filter a properties file in the asset directory of my project. This is so i don't have to keep changing values between dev, SIT and prod versions of my app. I'm using maven & intelliJ IDEA with (eventually) different profiles, but for the moment i'm just trying to get the build process to pick up the filtered assets directory (if it is at all possible)

i've added these resource lines to my POM:

```
<resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>assets</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <targetPath>
        ../assets
    </targetPath>
</resource>

<resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>assets</directory>
    <excludes>
       <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <targetPath>
       ../assets
    </targetPath>
</resource>
```

Is there a way i can get the build process to look at the filtered assets directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/assets</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</targetPath>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>resources</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <sdk>
          <platform>7</platform>
        </sdk>
        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Check out the MorseFlash Sample project [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples).