# Unable to build android project with maven (android-maven-plugin)

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Strange behavior, sometimes I can package my project, most of the time I cannot.
The problem happens in `android:dex`:

```
$ mvn clean android:dex
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/danny/workspace/test/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.3.2:dex (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, /home/danny/.bin/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar, --dex, --output=/home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes.dex, /home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes]
[INFO] 
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.RuntimeException: /home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes: file not found
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:134)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
[INFO] 1 error; aborting
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.914s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 07 20:17:03 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.2:dex (default-cli) on project test: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /home/danny/workspace/test && /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024M -jar /home/danny/.bin/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar --dex --output=/home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes.dex /home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes, Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I cannot find any information on this...
My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <name>Test</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <assetsDirectory>src/main/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>src/main/resources</resourceDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>8</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT**

Running `mvn package` results in:

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.3.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ test ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] /home/danny/.bin/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt [package, -m, -J, /home/danny/workspace/test/target/generated-sources/r, -M, /home/danny/workspace/test/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/resources, --auto-add-overlay, -A, /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/assets, -I, /home/danny/.bin/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/android.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/danny/workspace/test/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/danny/workspace/test/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/java/com/example/test/gui/MainActivity.java:[17,18] package R does not exist
[ERROR] /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/java/com/example/test/gui/MainActivity.java:[26,29] package R does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.960s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 07 22:40:35 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/86M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/java/com/example/test/gui/MainActivity.java:[17,18] package R does not exist
[ERROR] /home/danny/workspace/test/src/main/java/com/example/test/gui/MainActivity.java:[26,29] package R does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: `package R does not exist`is highly because of `non existing resourceDirectory /home/danny/workspace/test/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/resources`. You are not using resource filtering correctly. Check out answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128906/filtering-an-assets-file-android?lq=1) to see how to setup resource filtering in pom.xml. Or if you don't intend to use resource filtering, do not modify the default <assetsDirectory> and <resourceDirectory> in android-maven-plugin configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated `R` file used the package declaration `com.example.test` (which is the groupId of my project) and I tried to access it in the class `com.example.test.gui.MainActivity`. So I needed to import `com.example.test.R` explicitly.

Comment: In hindsight, this one seems so obvious, but I totally missed it too!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can tell you that, based on that log, your builder is deleting all the files in a folder right before it tries to dex that folder - thus, the dex fails as there is nothing there. However, I have no idea why this is happening as I don't see you having invoked the maven-clean-plugin anywhere. I have seen similar issues happen where builds work if you call `mvn clean`, then `mvn install`, but will NOT work if you call `mvn clean install`; however, I have only seen this in large custom builds where people are calling the clean plugin themselves. However, it's possible it may also help your situation, even though I can't see what's causing it...

EDIT: Sorry, it's still early for me. The problem isn't the clean, the problem is that the compiler plugin is never running. After the clean you will generally have any resources you need getting generated, then your code gets compiled, and THEN the classes will get dexed. You are never generating your .class files, so there is nothing to dex.

Comment: I thought android:apk runs the build stuff as well before... Trying to build the java files I'm getting `package R does not exist`. `mvn android:generate-sources` didnt helped...

Comment: The R file is generated by aapt, which should also be running automatically before any of the other stuff... The basic progression would be that the R file is created during generate-sources, then your classes are compiled in the compile phase, then the classes are dexed, and then the actual APK is produced during the packaging phase. What is the output when you run `mvn generate-sources`?

Comment: Hold on, is the above output from when you type `mvn android:dex`? What happens when you just type `mvn package`?

Comment: Yes its from `mvn android:dex` When running `mvn package` I'm getting `package R does not exist`. `mvn generate-sources` works, but running `mvn package` then results in the same `package R does not exist`.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you are trying to run the phases yourself. Maven is nice in that if you tell it to run a phase it will figure out all the phases on which that phase depends and run them too. So, you only have to tell it the last phase you need run (usually `mvn package` or `mvn install`) and it will automatically run all the prereqs. You can see one of the dangers of not doing this in your log above - it ran a clean right before it tried to dex! If you are getting errors when you run `mvn package` then there might be a problem with your code. What happens in `generate-sources`?

Comment: Actually, can you just update your post with the log output from when you run `mvn package`?

Comment: I've updated my post now. `generate-sources` generates `R.java` and `BuildConfig.java` in `target/generated-sources/r/com/example/test`.

Comment: If there is really an R.java file in the target/generated-sources folder I am not sure why the compiler plugin isn't finding it. Is the package of the R file (you can see this by opening it in a text editor) the same as the package of the files which cannot seem to see it? Also, it says there are 3 source files but only two files with errors - is the third source file able to successfully reference the R file?

Comment: `R.java` uses `package com.example.test` and `MainActivity.java` uses `package com.example.test.gui`.